# Get div and the correct close tag preg

Tags: php

Now preg has always been a tool to me that i like but i cant figure out for the life if me if what i want to do is possible let and how to do it is going over my head

What i want is preg_match to be able to return me a div's innerHTML the problem is the div im tring to read has more divs in it and my preg keeps closing on the first  tag it find

Here is my Actual code

```
$scrape_address = "http://isohunt.com/torrent_details/133831593/98e034bd6382e0f4ecaa9fe2b5eac01614edc3c6?tab=summary";
$ch = curl_init($scrape_address);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$data = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('% <div id="torrent_details">(.*)</div> %six', $data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

This has been updated for TomcatExodus's help

Live at :: http://megatorrentz.com/beta/details.php?hash=98e034bd6382e0f4ecaa9fe2b5eac01614edc3c6

Comment: Do you have a special reason for not using a HTML parser instead?

Comment: nope i just could not find one that loaded with any sort of speed and speed is an issue

Comment: why has some one downed my question i gave examples of what i wanted just in case my wording was not correct?

Comment: @Barkermn01 People are all over the `HTML cannot be parsed with regex` bandwagon/fad since the famous answer on SO, and seem to get easily offended by others who don't explicitly realize this. I'll upvote to offset.

Comment: Upvoting doesn't offset a downvote, it does so 5 times over. Upvote questions that you genuinely feel are "useful and clear".

Comment: yea i was not asking for a upvote i was asking the person who downed it to explain why they did that was all,

Comment: I doubt that a HTML parser is notably slower for this than a regular expression. It would be the right way to go.

Comment: Well could you recomend a good one as an answer then pls?

Comment: Show us your preg_match please.

Comment: @David Dorward Offset doesn't always have to mean 1:1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$scrape_address = "http://isohunt.com/torrent_details/133831593/98e034bd6382e0f4ecaa9fe2b5eac01614edc3c6?tab=summary";
$ch = curl_init($scrape_address);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($data);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$div = $domd->getElementById("torrent_details");

if ($div) {
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  $dom2->appendChild($dom2->importNode($div, true));
  echo $dom2->saveHTML();
} else {
  echo "Has no element with the given ID\n";
}
```

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::importNode() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, null given in /var/www/mega/beta/details.php on line 37

Warning: DOMNode::appendChild() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, null given in /var/www/mega/beta/details.php on line 37

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::importNode() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given`

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on my machine, is it on yours? The html will not get loaded without it this way, so it won't find the node with that id.

Comment: Tryed your new one still same errors and thats the way i had it before i dont use file_get...

Comment: I get that error when `$data` is empty. Please make sure it gets loaded, and it contains an element with that ID.

Comment: I've tried the same approach as you Maerlyn, i can get the html from the url, but feeding it to DomDocument results in a null value, i've also sent it through tidy before, but no use either. Is it at least working for you?

Comment: I've updated the code again to include some error handling. Does print the error for isohunt.com's index page, echoes the correct div in case of the OP's url. I'm using php 5.3.3.

Comment: I'm using php 5.2.1 but i dont get it when i use the url i have provided, 

it just tells me "Has no element with the given ID" but then i view source and it is there "<div id="torrent_details"><b>Trackers:</b>" even if i right $data to a file and read the file it still shows is there. but DOM cant find it

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I've copypasted the exact code that works here? Maybe DOM internals have changed? I'm hoping someone smarter comes by.

Comment: How did you get it working? I'm assuming you did, as you accepted it.

Comment: I tried your code, the problem is dtd-related as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: i got it working using Simple XML just insted of DOMDocument i used Simple to load the document.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression leads often to problems when parsing markup documents.

XPath version - independent of the source layout. The only thing you need is a div with that id.

```
loadHTMLFile($url);
$xp = new domxpath($dom);
$result = $xp->query("//*[@id = 'torrent_details']");
$div=$result->item(0);

if($result->length){
    $out =new DOMDocument();
    $out->appendChild($out->importNode($div, true));
    echo $out->saveHTML();
}else{
    echo "No such id";
}
?>
```

And this is the fix for Maerlyn solution. It didn't work because getElementById() wants a DTD with the id attribute specified. I mean, you can always build a document with "apple" as the record id, so you need something that says "id" is really the id for this tag.

```
validateOnParse = true;
@$domd->loadHTML($data);

//this doesn't work as the DTD is not specified
//or the specified id attribute is not the attributed called "id"

//$div = $domd->getElementById("torrent_details");

/*
 * workaround found here: https://fosswiki.liip.ch/display/BLOG/GetElementById+Pitfalls
 * set the "id" attribute as the real id
 */
$elements = $domd->getElementsByTagName('div');
if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    //try-catch needed because of elements with no id
    try{
    $element->setIdAttribute('id', true);
    }catch(Exception $e){}
}
}

//now it works
$div = $domd->getElementById("torrent_details");

//Print its content or error
if ($div) {
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  $dom2->appendChild($dom2->importNode($div, true));
  echo $dom2->saveHTML();
} else {
  echo "Has no element with the given ID\n";
}

?>
```

Both of the solutions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('% <div \s+ id="torrent_details">(?<innerHtml>.*)</div> %six', $html, $match);
echo $match['innerHtml'];
```

That one will work, but you should only need `preg_match` not `preg_match_all` if the pages are written well, there should only be one instance of `id="torrent_details"` on the given page.

---

I'm retracting my answer. This will not work properly. Use `DOM` for navigating the document.

Comment: Thanks trying now will it support me adding the id="someid" well i am trying it with that now

Comment: Sure, it will support `<div class="myClass" id="myId" foo="bar" etc="etc">`

Comment: Or did you mean capturing the `id`?

Comment: Sorry it's not working because of the `x` modifier, it allows ignore-whitespace. I use it for readability in long regex strings. Remove the `x` modifier, or use `\s` or `\s+` for whitespace inclusion.

Comment: http://megatorrentz.com/beta/details.php?hash=98e034bd6382e0f4ecaa9fe2b5eac01614edc3c6

Comment: I've updated it again, using `\s+` for whitespace inclusion. Drop the `+` if you're certain there will only be a single space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
/]*>(.*)<\/div>/i

Which would give you the largest possible innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. I will not link to the famous question, because I dislike the pointless drivel on top. But still regular expressions are unfit to match nested structures.

You can use some trickery, but this is neither reliable, nor necessarily fast:

```
preg_match_all('#<div id="1">((<div>.*?</div>|.)*?)</div>#ims'
```

Your regex had a problem due to the `/x` flag not matching the opening div. And you used a wrong assertion notation.

Answer (score 0):

haha did it with a bit of tampering thanks for the DOMDocument idea i just to use simple

```
$ch = curl_init($scrape_address);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

print_r($xml->body->table->tr->td->table[2]->tr->td[0]->span[0]->div);
```

Comment: Your solution works but it's quite much dependence on that page's HTML structure.